# Laravel | Edit 2 tables

Tags: laravel, edit

I need help editing 2 tables. When I do the introduction of data in the BD I do it for 2 tables:

```
$tabela = new funcionario();
$tabela->nome = $request->nome;
$tabela->email = $request->email;
$result = $tabela->save();

$tabela4 = new feria(); 
$tabela4->id_funcionario = $tabela->id;
$tabela4->n_ferias_disponiveis = $request->n_ferias_disponiveis;

$tabela4->save();
```

When I edit, I use this code:

```
$item->nome = $request->nome;
$item->email = $request->email;

$item->n_ferias_disponiveis = $request->n_ferias_disponiveis;
$item->data_registo = $now;
```

But I can't edit `n_ferias_disponiveis`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with `I can't edit `n_ferias_disponiveis`? And quick tip, code in English...

Comment: you should add more detail, this question is not clear at all

Comment: Don't you just missed to call `$item->save();` on the edit code? Or do you have an SQL error when you save it?

Comment: I have an error for not finding that field in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to share a bit more of the update method but so far, this is my guess:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$vacation = Vacation::find(1);

$user->nome = $request->nome;
$user->email = $request->email;

$vacation->n_ferias_disponiveis = $request->n_ferias_disponiveis;
$vacation->data_registo = $now;

$user->save(); // <- don't forget to save you changes!!
$vacation->save(); // <- don't forget to save you changes!!
```

For more information on update methods for eloquent refer to [Inserting & Updating Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

You may also check out Laravels [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships). My guess is, you have a users table and a vacation table. This could be a many-to-many relation or an one-to-many relationship. Updating such Eloquent Relationships is way more efficient.

Comment: how does he know that the name and email belong to the user table and n_ferias_avaniveis belongs to the vacation table?

Comment: I've updated my post with the second model and some notes to eloquent relationships

Comment: I try use ::find(1); But it's going to fetch the wrong ID. 
So I tried ::find($item->id); But it gives me the following error Creating default object from empty value